# unsigned long larger than 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, integer, overflow, sizeof

How test program can result 4294967297 if unsigned long maximum is 4294967295?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned long millis_diff(unsigned long then, unsigned long now) {
    return now < then ? now + then : now - then;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned long now = 2;
    unsigned long then = 4294967295; //unsigned long maximum value
    unsigned long diff = millis_diff(then, now);
    cout << diff;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "unsigned long maximum is 4294967295?"
No it isn't...

Comment: "*unsigned long maximum is 4294967295*" this is incorrect premise in general.

Comment: Let me guess, you are using linux?

Comment: How do you know that's the maximum?

Comment: C++ gives you two guarantees with the integer types. The first is that the condition `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) && sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) && sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) && sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)` will be `true`. The second is that `long` will be *at least* a 32-bit data-type. A `long` could be 64 bits as well.

Comment: Have you checked `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()` on your system?

Comment: Typically, for 64-bit PC-like targets GCC will have 64-bit `long`. The Visual C++ compiler will have 32 bit `long` even for 64-bit targets.

Comment: The only guarantee you get about `unsigned long` is that it is greater than or equal to `unsigned int`. The actual size is implementation defined.

Comment: I seriously don't checked max sizes...

It's now that table of integer sizes is invalid?

unsigned char is 0..255   (1 byte value)
unsigned short is 0..65535 (2 bytes unsigned value)
unsigned long 0..4294967295 (4 bytes unsigned value)
unsigned long long 0..0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (8 bytes value)

Comment: @EugeneX, table of integer sizes is highly architecture-dependent and ABI-dependent. It's not the same across all the platforms.

Comment: There are target systems (typically DPS's) where a `char` could be 16 bits. And there are old systems where a "character" could 6, 7, or 9 bits, and "word" (typically `int`) could be 18 or 36 bits. In short, the integer types does not have a fixed size in the specification, only minimum sizes. And remember, even though `char` could be any number of bits, `sizeof(char)` will *always* equal `1`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that it seems your compiler defines `unsigned long int` the same way as it defines `unsigned long long int`.:)

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof( unsigned long ) = " << sizeof( unsigned long ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "The maximum values is " << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( unsigned long ) = 8
The maximum values is 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Thank you about description, Now I will know that ulong is 8 bytes long...

Comment: `Now I will know that ulong is 8 bytes long` You know that it is 8 bytes *on that particular system*. That assumption won't hold on systems where it isn't 8 bytes.

Comment: @EugeneX It's not always this way. The standard only guarantees it to be at least 32 bits.

Comment: @EugeneX It depends on the used compiler. Some implementations define its size as 4 bytes others as 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

> How test program can result 4294967297 if unsigned long maximum is 4294967295?

Given the premise, it can't.

However, there is no guarantee for `unsigned long` maximum to be exactly 4'294'967'295, so your premise may be invalid. that maximum corresponds to the maximum that a 32 bit number can represent. 32 is the *minimum* required width for (`unsigned`) `long`, but it may be wider than that.

In particular, it is typical for some 64 bit systems to have `unsigned long` of 64 bits, which has the maximum value of 18'446'744'073'709'551'615.